# Select & Send Multiple documents as an attachment in a Document set?

Tags: document-set

How to Select and Send Multiple documents as an attachment in a Document Set? I really appreciate your detailed response.

Thanks,
John.

Comment: Are you looking to be able to send an entire document set as an email attachment? Are you wanting to selecting multiple individual files inside  document set to attach to an email. Can you clarify your question a bit please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the tool from Codeplex, which would send individual and multiple documents as an email attachment - http://sendemailsp2010.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: I need to send multiple individual files inside document set to SharePoint Security Groups. The above mentioned codeplex tool allows to select multiple documents. But I want to send to SharePoint Security Groups.